# WCF Service instead of ASMX Web Service?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, wcf, web-services, soap, asmx

I'm writing a SOAP Server that will act as an endpoint for an external client. The external client expects SOAP 1.1. I'll be taking embedded business objects in the SOAP messages and passing them to an internal application, getting responses back and responding with SOAP messages to the eternal client.

I did the traditional ASMX based web services several years ago. Now, I've been exploring WCF Services and wondering the best approach to take.

1) Should WCF be considered a superset of ASMX web services?

2) Is there any reason to still write new web services using ASMX instead of WCF?

3) Does WCF provide better facilities for working with SOAP messages, as opposed to SOAP Extensions?

4) Can I restrict communication to SOAP 1.1 using WCF, the way I can with a web.config change in ASMX?

5) Does WCF have an easy way to log or review the requests that hit the service without resorting to something like SOAP extensions?

Sorry my questions are not very specific; still trying to get handle on what I need to know...

Using VS2008, Windows Server 2008.

Chris

Comment: possible duplicate of [Web Services -- WCF vs. Standard](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6666/web-services-wcf-vs-standard)

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/wcf+asmx

Comment: see http://keithelder.net/blog/archive/2008/10/17/WCF-vs-ASMX-WebServices.aspx

Comment: Thanks to everyone on their feedback. I'm going to try to do it using WCF; does anyone know where I can find any good examples of parsing/working with SOAP messages within VS2008? I'm struggling to get a working web service using either asmx or wcf with SOAP.

Comment: You don't parse messages with WCF - you add a Service Reference. See http://johnwsaundersiii.spaces.live.com/blog/cns!600A2BE4A82EA0A6!790.entry for one example, and see http://msdn.microsoft.com/wcf/ for a lot more.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would recommend that you use WCF. If you configure your WCF service to use basichttpbinding, it will work as a SOAP 1.1 service.

1. WCF "replaces" several communication technologies, including asmx.
2. I cannot think of any technical reason. You may do it if you have a team that knows asmx but not wcf, or you have a project with a lot of asmx services and you do not want to introduce a new technology.
3. WCF has [message contracts](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms730255.aspx), but not 100% sure what you mean here.
4. Yes, basic http binding
5. Yes, you can use [WCF tracing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733025.aspx?PHPSESSID=50d760d9b862023e2c39e99ef0c83e42)

Comment: About point 2, I can't think of any **technical** reasons but there may be other reasons.

Comment: +1 Information about WCF tracing is very interesting and it was new for me. @wchrisjohnson: ASMX give you one very direct way to write web services. WCF gives you a lot of customizing possibilities, so you receive a method to choose the way which are the most suitable for every your development project.