# Windows Form .Net 1.1 & WCF

Tags: .net, winforms, wcf, frameworks, .net-1.1

I've been tasked with finding out if it's possible to have a WCF service that can be hooked into by a Windows .Net 1.1 application, as well as newer web applications and one mobile app.

I've done a fair bit of reading on the subject but I've got next to no experience on winforms or the .net framework prior to 2.0.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks,

James

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have any experience of this myself, but I've found a post on [Rob Windsor's Weblog](http://msmvps.com/blogs/windsor/archive/2008/05/17/calling-wcf-services-from-net-1-1.aspx) which indicates that it is possible.

This, in turn, points to an MSDN article on [ASMX Client with a WCF Service](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms751433.aspx) and points out a further thing you need to consider.

The MSDN article is a general sample that

> ... demonstrates how to create a service using Windows Communication Foundation (WCF) and then access the service from a non-WCF client, such as an ASMX client.

Answer (score 0):

WCF requires minimum Framework 3.0.

But WCF basicHttpBinding is SOAP 1.1, ASMX is also SOAP 1.1

So your .net 1.1 client can use a WCF basicHttpBinding service as if it was a standard web service.

See also: [WCF Service instead of ASMX Web Service?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2841221/wcf-service-instead-of-asmx-web-service/2841269#2841269)