# What are the Advantage of WCF Service Over WebService 2.0 in Performance?

Tags: wcf, web-services

I Want to know the Advantages of WCF Service and Webservice 2.0 in performance wise,
Please give me some imprtant links to know more about this.

Comment: When you say "WebService 2.0" do you mean ASMX web services?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Web Services -- WCF vs. Standard](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6666/web-services-wcf-vs-standard)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may find [this article on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb310550.aspx) interesting:

> To summarize the results, WCF is
>   25%—50% faster than ASP.NET Web
>   Services, and approximately 25% faster
>   than .NET Remoting.