# what are the advantages of wcf service with basicHttp over ASMX Web Services

Tags: wcf, web-services

Purpose is to develop **basic services without any security mechanism**.

What advantage we can get using **WCF service with basicHttpBinding** over **ASMX web services**.

UPDATE :
WCF does have many advantages over asmx web services, but what's with specific case of **basicHttp** binding ?

One advantage is - WCF service is faster due to performance improvement by using DataContract serializer over XMLSerializer used by asmx web services.

Comment: WCF services **ARE** web services.....

Comment: possible duplicate of [Web Services -- WCF vs. Standard](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6666/web-services-wcf-vs-standard)

Comment: Microsoft considers ASMX web services to be a "legacy technology". Don't use them unless you have to.

Answer (score 0):

Cross-platform compatability is the first thing that jumps to mind. If you have non-WCF web service clients they are more likely to be able to use your web service if it uses basicHttpBinding or wsHttpBinding.