# WebServices ASMX - WCF

Tags: wcf, web-services, jqgrid, asmx

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Web Services — WCF vs. Standard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6666/web-services-wcf-vs-standard)

I'm thinking about to know if I'm following the right way by choose a technology for my WebService.
My WebServices will be always consumed from js/jQuery methods and always will return serialized JSON data (for jQuery function and to load jqGrids) not objects.
My site use WIF authentication, but I think this make no difference.

Because of this prerequisites I choose the ASMX technology; is simple and for my needs I think it's ok.

A good reference was: http://keithelder.net/2008/10/17/WCF-vs-ASMX-WebServices/

According to support, security and speed is the right choice? Or is better to move my WebServices to WCF technology?

Comment: I don't think that ASMX supports WIF. Not very cleanly if at all. This question is a duplicate of the original I linked. Take a look at the original and remember that ASMX is now three years older than it was at the time of that question, and has had almost no bugs fixed in the interim.

Comment: Thanks. From my starting tests is working well with WIF. I don't know if the jqGrid works fine with WCF, with ASMX works perfectly.

Comment: WCF supports everything that ASMX supported. It completely replaces ASMX.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For jqGrid and WCF WebService I find a useful post on trirand forum: http://www.trirand.com/blog/?page_id=393/discussion/jqgrid-and-wcf-issue/; hope I will start to work my grids too.

Ok, I get that if I use (and understand) WCF I get only advantages and is better if I replace my services to this technology.

I have windows (MFC - c++) programs that will communicate with my service; I hope they will work fine with WCF services.

Thanks for the suggestions.