# what is WCF and how does it work?

Tags: wcf, web-services, soap, asmx

what is this WCF ? i used web services little bit but don't know about theses WCF, read a lot on google but couldn't get its technical terms like 
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/139787/What-s-the-Difference-between-WCF-and-Web-Services 
or msdn.

It says like communication over HTTP and SOAP , serialization, soap etc but yet I'm not qualified to understand these. Help me, guide me and please in easy wordings.

```
[WebService] 
public class Service : System.Web.Services.WebService 
{ 
  [WebMethod] 
  public string Test(string strMsg) 
  { 
      return strMsg; 
  } 
}
```

etc
and how to use them with asp.net ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Web Services -- WCF vs. Standard](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6666/web-services-wcf-vs-standard)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! ASMX is a legacy technology, and should not be used for new development. WCF or ASP.NET Web API should be used for all new development of web service clients and servers. One hint: Microsoft has retired the [ASMX Forum](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/asmxandxml/threads) on MSDN.

Comment: ok what does serialization etc mean in this context ?

Comment: You should read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6666/web-services-wcf-vs-standard.

Comment: it say 
you can get a service running not-too-hellishly with some copy&paste and filling the blanks but it will take most developers months before they understand what all that configuration and setup actually does.

so would i have to learn configuration ? is that necessary ?

Comment: Read the whole thing, not just one comment by one person.

Answer (score 4):

Windows communication foundation or Wcf is a framework for building services. Wcf supports exposing web services, services based on urls (rest) or services ment only to work on a single machine, such as two different programs communicating via shared memory.

Basically wcf abstracts the service (a .net interface) and the transport (or in wcf terms, a binding). A single service in Wcf can be exposed as a web service or using shared memory without any actual code changes, the endpoints are all based on app config files.

Perhaps this article on msdn will make things clearer
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731082.aspx

Some terms,
**Interoperability** - to operate, or work together, with something else (inter- between, operate- work together) a wcf service can *interoperate* with a client written in java for example

**Serialization** - to convert an object to a stream of bytes that can be sent somewhere and then *deserialized* back into an object

Comment: so if someone writes a web service in JAVA then would taht be accessible from asp.net ?

Comment: what an interoperability mean here ?

Comment: yes, as long as the java service uses a standard service protocol, like soap

Comment: Nice answer, but a close-as-duplicate vote would have been more helpful.

Comment: Possibly, but I think what op is asking is more basic than the comparison between asmx and wcf. I think he's trying to understand what wcf even is

Comment: @JohnSaunders not everything is duplicate. Try to look into what the person is asking.